# The value disappears but still save in database

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I have a registration form for a Python/Django project that uses Vue.js. I save the form correctly, but when trying to edit, I can see that the value is loaded properly, but it disappears very quickly, as if Vue.js/JavaScript is erasing it. When inspecting the field, I can see that its value receives the correct value from the registration, but the field becomes blank.

```
<script>
function capitalizeWords(string) {
    if (!string) return string;
    const words = string.split(' ');
    const capitalizedWords = words.map((word) => {
        if (word.length > 1) {
            return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        } else {
            return word.toUpperCase();
        }
    });

    return capitalizedWords.join(' ');
}

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
        street: '',
        district: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        country: '',
        cnpj: '',
        name: '',
        trade_name: '',
        cnae: '',
        opening_date: '',
        selectedBank: '',
        bank: '',
        bank_code: '',
        nameInBankAccount: '',
        cnpjInBankAccount: '',  
        postal_code: '',
        isLoading: false,
        isPostalCodeFound: true,
        isCNPJFound: true,
        display_form_address: false,
        display_form_bank: false,
        hasError: '{{ error }}'
    },
    beforeMount: function () {
        this.street = this.$el.querySelector('#id_address-0-street').value
        this.district = this.$el.querySelector('#id_address-0-district').value
        this.city = this.$el.querySelector('#id_address-0-city').value
        this.state = this.$el.querySelector('#id_address-0-state').value
        this.country = this.$el.querySelector('#id_address-0-country').value
        this.cnpj = this.$el.querySelector('#id_company-cnpj').value
        this.name = this.$el.querySelector('#id_company-name').value
        this.trade_name = this.$el.querySelector('#id_company-trade_name').value
        this.cnae = this.$el.querySelector('#id_company-cnae').value
        this.opening_date = this.$el.querySelector('#id_company-opening_date').value
        this.getError();
    },
    watch: {
        cnpj: function(newValue) {
            this.cnpjInBankAccount = newValue;
        },
        name: function(newValue) {
            this.nameInBankAccount = newValue;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isBankDisabled: function() {
            return this.selectedBank !== '';
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onPostalCodeChange() {
            if (this.postal_code.length >= 8) {
                this.fetchPostalCodeData()
            } else {
                this.postal_code = ''
                this.street = ''
                this.district = ''
                this.city = ''
                this.state = ''
                this.isPostalCodeFound = true
            }
        },
        onCNPJChange() {
            if (this.cnpj.length === 14) {
                this.fetchCNPJData()
            } else {
                this.name = ''
                this.trade_name = ''
                this.cnae = ''
                this.opening_date = ''
                this.isCNPJFound = true
            }
        },
        showAddress: function () {
            this.display_form_address = !this.display_form_address;
        },
        showBank: function () {
            this.display_form_bank = !this.display_form_bank;
        },
        getError: function () {
            if (this.hasError === "True"){
                this.showBank();
                this.showAddress();
            }
        },
        async fetchPostalCodeData() {
            try {
                this.isLoading = true
                const response = await fetch(
                    `https://viacep.com.br/ws/${this.postal_code}/json/`, {
                        method: 'GET',
                    })
                const data = await response.json()
                if (data.erro == true || data.erro == 'true'){
                    this.isPostalCodeFound = false
                } else {
                    console.log(data)
                    this.street = data.logradouro
                    this.district = data.bairro
                    this.city = data.localidade
                    this.state = data.uf
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            } finally {
                this.isLoading = false
            }
        },
        async fetchCNPJData() {
            try {
                this.isLoading = true
                const response = await fetch(
                    `link da api`, {
                        method: 'GET',
                    })
                const data = await response.json()
                console.log(data)
                console.log(response.status)
                if (response.status === 404) {
                    this.isCNPJFound = false
                } else {
                    this.name = capitalizeWords(data.name)
                    this.trade_name = capitalizeWords(data.trading_name)
                    this.opening_date = data.fundation_date
                    this.cnae = data.cnae_code
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            } finally {
                this.isLoading = false
            }
        },

    }
})
```

The fields that are being cleared are:
bank
bank_code
I can't understand the reason for these values being cleared; I believe it might be related to the loading of JS/Vue.js, but I can't assert that with clarity. Nonetheless, the values are correctly saved in the database.

The form is:

```
class BuyerLegalPersonBankAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
select_bank = MajorBankList(
    label='Banco',
    required=False,
    )
class Meta:
    model = CompanyBankAccount
    fields = (
        'name',
        'cpf',
        'cnpj',
        'select_bank',
        'bank',
        'bank_code',
        'agency',
        'account',
        'account_type',
    )
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['bank'].required = False
    self.fields['bank_code'].required = False
    self.fields['bank'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'bank',
            ':disabled': 'isBankDisabled',
        }
    )
    self.fields['bank_code'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'bank_code',
            ':disabled': 'isBankDisabled',
        }
    )
    self.fields['select_bank'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'selectedBank',
        }
    )
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'nameInBankAccount',
        }
    )
    self.fields['cnpj'].widget.attrs.update(
        {
            'v-model': 'cnpjInBankAccount',
        }
    )
```

Comment: where in your code are `bank` and `bank_code` even referenced/populated?

Comment: i have edited the aweser